# Proof: $a,b \in \overline{\Bbb{R}}$, $a\leq b < +\infty \wedge a \in \Bbb{R} \Rightarrow b \in \Bbb{R}$

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

I must to proof the following:

- ***Prop.***: let be $a,b \in \overline{\Bbb{R}}$ then:$$a\leq b < +\infty \wedge a \in \Bbb{R} \Rightarrow b \in \Bbb{R}$$
- ***Proof***: by contradiction I have $b \notin \Bbb{R}$ therefore $b \in \{+\infty,-\infty\}$, so $$b=+\infty \vee b=-\infty$$ if $b=+\infty$ then $a\leq +\infty < +\infty $, but $+\infty<+\infty \equiv +\infty \leq +\infty \wedge +\infty \neq +\infty$ and it is an absurd

  if $b=-\infty$ then $a\leq -\infty < +\infty $, but by definition of $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ we have $\forall a \in \Bbb{R}(-\infty < a<+\infty)$ therefore ($\leq$ is total order) I have $a \leq -\infty \wedge -\infty <a$ then $a=-\infty \wedge a \neq -\infty$ and it is an absurd

Is it correct?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.=$\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ is  [R union {+infty,-infty}](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffinelyExtendedRealNumbers.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. However, it can be solved much easier by noting that $-\infty<a\le b<\infty$ implies $-\infty\neq b\neq \infty$, so $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: oh thanks soo much! :)

Comment: your proof is direct! ;)